# Variable php redirect based on url

Tags: php, redirect, http-redirect

i'm creating a index.php file for redirect all website to specific host 
I'd like create a little php script that read url and redirect based on specific filter.

for example: 
if url = (everything).domain1.com redir to default1.php
if url = (everything).domain2.com redir to default2.php
in all other case that not like first or second redir to default3.php

this is possible with php? i must use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] or can I use other method?

Comment: For that task will be better to use RewriteCond in `.htaccess`

Comment: yes like previous comment do this in htaccess load of questions like this on SO

Comment: yes, i know, but i can't use .htaccess

Comment: why cant you use it? if you have ftp access you can use it

Comment: and if i use .htaccess what can I write inside file?

Comment: you can use redirect     "redirect x1.php http://www.x2.com/x2.php"

Answer (score 1):

i resolved with:

```
    <?php 
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
if (strpos($domain,'domain-name.com') == true) {
    header('location: /index2.php');
    exit();
} else {
    header('location: /index3.php');
}
?>
```

but not redirect...